# как задействовать чёрные списки dns при приёме почты?

Tags: debian, exim

существуют разные [«чёрные списки dns» (dns blacklists, dnsbl)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL).

как в *exim* воспользоваться их возможностями и сразу блокировать соединения с ip-адресов, «засветившихся» в этих списках?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в конфигурации программы *exim*, установленной из *debian*-овских репозиториев (в *ubuntu*-вских, вероятно, аналогично), уже есть необходимая «заготовка».

1. в файле `/etc/exim4/conf.d/acl/30_exim4-config_check_rcpt` (если при установке был выбран пункт «не разбивать конфигурацию на отдельные файлы», то ищите в содержимом файла `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`) присутствуют такие строки в секции `acl_check_rcpt:` :

   ```
     # Check against classic DNS "black" lists (DNSBLs) which list
     # sender IP addresses
     .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS
     warn
       dnslists = CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS
       add_header = X-Warning: $sender_host_address is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
       log_message = $sender_host_address is listed at $dnslist_domain ($dnslist_value: $dnslist_text)
     .endif
   ```

   вам надо заменить здесь директиву `warn` на директиву `deny` (благодаря чему *exim* будет не только посылать предупреждение, но и прекращать сеанс связи).
2. и, собственно, надо определить используемую в указанном фрагменте переменную `CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS` (по умолчанию она не определена и фрагмент, соответственно, не задействован).

   самое логичное место для этого определения — `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/000_localmacros` (в случае «единого конфигурационного файла», как и сказано выше, редактируйте файл [`/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros`](https://wiki.debian.org/Exim#Single_Exim4_configuration_file)).

   для того, чтобы проверялись списки от [spamhaus.org](https://www.spamhaus.org/zen/), добавьте такую строку:

   ```
   CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS = zen.spamhaus.org
   ```

   в принципе, конечно, можно добавить (через двоеточие) и другие списки. например, от [spamcop.net](https://www.spamcop.net/fom-serve/cache/408.html):

   ```
   CHECK_RCPT_IP_DNSBLS = zen.spamhaus.org:bl.spamcop.net
   ```

   имеет ли смысл удлинять список, и что именно туда включать — это уже на ваше усмотрение.
3. если у вас конфигурация [разбита (по умолчанию) на отдельные файлы](https://wiki.debian.org/Exim#Split_file), теперь вам надо обновить её командой:

   ```
   $ sudo update-exim4.conf
   ```
4. всё, можно перезапускать *exim*:

   ```
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/exim4 restart
   ```

---

если всё сделано верно, вскоре вы увидите в логах что-нибудь типа этого:

> H=(retract.nfathera.date) [45.119.43.8] F= rejected RCPT : 45.119.43.8 is listed at zen.spamhaus.org (127.0.0.3: https://www.spamhaus.org/sbl/query/SBLCSS)